# External Object general error message on login

Tags: lightning-connect, platform-bug, gack, externalobjects, salesforce-connect

When logging into an org as a System Admin, I receive the following error:

[image: General external object error]

The text of the error message: "Developer error in file apex://Order__x at line number -1"

Stack trace error message: "Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
Error ID: 334194590-82559 (116521520)"

Any idea why this error may be being thrown? What does this error mean for an external object? It looks like the Order__x external object is behaving as expected in all other contexts.

Upon refreshing, now the error is no longer appearing, even when logging out and logging back in. I have not made any changes to resolve this error and can no longer reproduce at all.

Answer (score 0):

That message "Error ID: 334194590-82559 (116521520)" is a [GACK](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) reference.

It's basically an internal Salesforce error code for something they didn't expect to occur.

The standard way to handle a GACK is to raise a support case. Make sure you include the Error ID clearly and identify it as a GACK.

Comment: That is says "Developer error in file apex://Order__x at line number -1" makes me think there was some kind of compilation issue. Especially since it isn't occurring on subsequent requests.